# How many displays on MacBook Pro 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, display

How many displays can I connect on my MacBook Pro early 2011?
Now I use extender monitor, but the screen of MacBook is off, like this
[macbook http://shrani.si/f/V/wG/3dRsX6iy/screen-shot-2014-02-18-a.png](http://shrani.si/f/V/wG/3dRsX6iy/screen-shot-2014-02-18-a.png)

and I forced my graphic card to non automatic switch
[monitor http://shrani.si/f/35/qq/4Oq2JVmK/screen-shot-2014-02-18-a.png](http://shrani.si/f/35/qq/4Oq2JVmK/screen-shot-2014-02-18-a.png)

My question is next: 
Can I use 2 LG TV displays? or I must buy MBP retina?

Greetings Andrej

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, since your computer has a Thunderbolt port (http://support.apple.com/kb/sp620). According to Apple, you can daisy-chain additional monitors using the Thunderbolt port:

> To make a desktop workstation out of your MacBook Pro, just daisy-chain additional Thunderbolt devices, including high-performance storage and video and audio capture devices, through the display. (http://www.apple.com/displays/, section "Expand the capabilities of your Mac")

Two monitors connected to one MacbookPro:
[image]

Comment: For your info, that's a retina Macbook Pro 13" on that picture.